# How can i replace " with \" in C#

Tags: c#

Input String is "How are you"
Expected output \"How are you\"

Due to combination of DoubleQuote and escape sequence I am not able to replace the string in the required format.

Please can someone provide me the code snippet for doing this.

I have tried below does not work

```
myString.Replace(""","\"");
```

Comment: filter.Replace(((char)34).ToString(), ((char)34).ToString() + ((char)92).ToString());

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that looks a little bit weird, you need to escape both:

```
string test = "\"How are you\"";
test = test.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape your backslash

```
myString.Replace("\"","\\\"");
```

This:

```
"\\\""
```

produces this:

```
\"
```

And also you should escape your double quote in first parameter.

And you can use `verbatim strings`,but there is a weird case about `double quote`, instead of `\"` you should use two double quotes `""` to escepe your charachter:

```
myString.Replace(@"""",@"\""");
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `"` and `\` have special meaning within a string literal and must be escaped with `\`.

So something like this:

```
myString.Replace("\"","\\\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "\"How are you\"";  
myString = myString.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```